# Hadoop Map-Reduce . RecordReader

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to solve the following RecordReader problem .
Example Input File :

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
.......
.......
```

i want my RecordReader to return

```
key | Value 
0   |1,1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5
4   |2,2:3,3:......6,6
6   |3,3:4,4......6,6,7,7
```

(for first value first  five line , for 2nd value five lines starting from 2nd line and for 3rd value five lines starting from 3rd line and so on    )

`public class MyRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {`

```
@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    while (pos < end) {
      key.set(pos);
      // five line logic 
      Text nextLine=new Text();



      int newSize = in.readLine(value, maxLineLength,
                                Math.max((int)Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end-pos),
                                         maxLineLength));
      fileSeek+=newSize;

      for(int n=0;n<4;n++)
      {
          fileSeek+=in.readLine(nextLine, maxLineLength,
                  Math.max((int)Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end-pos),
                           maxLineLength));
          value.append(":".getBytes(), 0,1);
          value.append(nextLine.getBytes(), 0, nextLine.getLength());
      }
      if (newSize == 0) {

        return false;

      }
      pos += newSize;
      if (newSize < maxLineLength) {

        return true;
      }

      // line too long. try again
      LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " + (pos - newSize));
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

But this is returning the values as

```
key | Value 
0   |1,1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5
4   |6,6:7,7.......10,10
6   |11,11:12,12:......14,14
```

can someone help me with this code or a fresh Code for RecodeReader will do as well ? 
[Requirement  of the problem (may help you understand the use case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455088/how-to-calculate-centered-moving-average-of-a-set-on-data-hadoop-map-reduce)
Thanks

Comment: please format the question properly, and show the output properly, then we might be able to answer...

Comment: @nyarlathotep : sry for bad format .
il try to improve it , 
still u could hv helped me wit an ans .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand the question... here's what I would do: wrap another RecordReader and buffer the keys/values from it into a local queue.

```
public class MyRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 5;
    private static final String DELIMITER = ":";

    private Queue<String> valueBuffer = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Queue<Long> keyBuffer = new LinkedList<Long>();
    private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
    private Text value = new Text();

    private RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> rr;
    public MyRecordReader(RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> rr) {
        this.rr = rr;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        rr.close();
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return rr.getProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        rr.initialize(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (valueBuffer.isEmpty()) {
            while (valueBuffer.size() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                if (rr.nextKeyValue()) {
                    keyBuffer.add(rr.getCurrentKey().get());
                    valueBuffer.add(rr.getCurrentValue().toString());
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (rr.nextKeyValue()) {
                keyBuffer.add(rr.getCurrentKey().get());
                valueBuffer.add(rr.getCurrentValue().toString());
                keyBuffer.remove();
                valueBuffer.remove();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        key.set(keyBuffer.peek());
        value.set(getValue());
        return true;
    }

    private String getValue() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> iter = valueBuffer.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(iter.next());
            if (iter.hasNext()) sb.append(DELIMITER);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Then for example, you can have a custom InputFormat that extends TextInputFormat and overrides the `createRecordReader` method to call `super.createRecordReader` and return that result wrapped in a `MyRecordReader`, like this:

```
public class MyTextInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {
    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
                InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1) {
        return new MyRecordReader(super.createRecordReader(arg0, arg1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't tested the code before running it. I edited it, try it now.