# How to calculate Centered Moving Average of a set of data in Hadoop Map-Reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to calculate Centered Moving average of a set of Data .

`Example Input format :`

```
quarter | sales      
Q1'11   | 9            
Q2'11   | 8
Q3'11   | 9
Q4'11   | 12
Q1'12   | 9
Q2'12   | 12
Q3'12   | 9
Q4'12   | 10
```

Mathematical Representation of data and calculation of Moving average and then centered moving average

```
Period   Value   MA  Centered
1          9
1.5
2          8
2.5              9.5
3          9            9.5
3.5              9.5
4          12           10.0
4.5              10.5
5          9            10.750
5.5              11.0
6          12
6.5
7          9
```

I am stuck with the implementation of RecordReader which will provide mapper sales value of a year i.e. of four quarter.

Comment: Why do you need MapReduce for this task?

Comment: We are implementing it using R ,but just wanted to use map-reduce to solve the problem .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually totally doable in the MapReduce paradigm; it does not have to be though of as a 'sliding window'. Instead think of the fact that each data point is relevant to a max of four MA calculations, and remember that each call to the map function can emit more than one key-value pair. Here is pseudo-code:

```
First MR job:

map(quarter, sales)
    emit(quarter - 1.5, sales)
    emit(quarter - 0.5, sales)
    emit(quarter + 0.5, sales)
    emit(quarter + 1.5, sales)

reduce(quarter, list_of_sales)
    if (list_of_sales.length == 4):
        emit(quarter, average(list_of_sales))
    endif


Second MR job:

map(quarter, MA)
    emit(quarter - 0.5, MA)
    emit(quarter + 0.5, MA)

reduce(quarter, list_of_MA)
    if (list_of_MA.length == 2):
        emit(quarter, average(list_of_sales))
    endif
```

Comment: I thought that map reduce makes sense when we have serious amount of data. And then we will have more then one mapper. In this case I am not sure how we will process data on mapper's boundary

Comment: @David, Yes, MapReduce is intended to operate on a large amount of data. And the idea is that in general, the map and reduce functions shouldn't care how many mappers or how many reducers there are, that's just optimization. If you think carefully about the algorithm I posted, you can see that it doesn't matter which mapper gets what portions of the data. Each input record will be available to every reduce operation that needs it.

Comment: I C! Nice! Indeed smart solution!

Answer (score 1):

In best of my understanding moving average is not nicely maps to MapReduce paradigm since its calculation is essentially "sliding window" over sorted data, while MR is processing of non-intersected  ranges of sorted data. 
Solution I do see is as following: 
a) To implement custom partitioner to be able to make two different partitions in two runs. In each run 
your reducers will get different ranges of data and calculate moving average where approprieate
I will try to illustrate: 
 
In first run data for reducers should be: 
R1: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 
R2: Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8 
...

here you will cacluate moving average for some Qs.

In next run your reducers should get data like:
R1: Q1...Q6 
R2: Q6...Q10 
R3: Q10..Q14

And caclulate the rest of moving averages. 
Then you will need to aggregate results.

Idea of custom partitioner that it will have two modes of operation - each time dividing into equal ranges but with some shift. In a pseudocode it will look like this : 
partition = (key+SHIFT) / (MAX_KEY/numOfPartitions) ; 
where:
 SHIFT will be taken from the configuration. 
 MAX_KEY =  maximum value of the key. I assume for simplicity that they start with zero.

RecordReader, IMHO is not a solution since it is limited to specific split and can not slide over split's boundary.

Another solution would be to implement custom logic of splitting input data (it is part of the InputFormat). It can be done to do 2 different slides, similar to partitioning.

Comment: Thanks  @David Gruzman 
I was trying to implement the RecordReader for "sliding input" to the mapper , but i am stuck there .[thread RecordReader Qus ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455088/how-to-calculate-centered-moving-average-of-a-set-on-data-hadoop-map-reduce)

Can you give more details on custom partitioner (logical) implementation ?